# git push has merged code from another branch. why?

Tags: git

Context : let's consider two branches "validation" and "develop".
I did some coding on develop, committed and pushed them. Then I switched to validation to code some fixes. These must not include the develop last commits, so I avoided any merge in any way and just checked out.

After coding a fix, I pull to get coworkers work, no conflict, and I push. And bam, the code from yesterday on develop has merged. I don't know why, and I need to know why to avoid making that mistake ever again.

Here are the list of my commands today :

`> git status`

```
On branch validation
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/validation'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

At this point I code my fix. Then I pull coworkers work to check for conflicts.

`> git pull`

```
remote: Counting objects: 81, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
remote: Total 81 (delta 59), reused 38 (delta 22)
Unpacking objects: 100% (81/81), done.
From http://url-repository/project
   659ae17..d32944f  branchC -> origin/branchC 
   dcabc87..9d7c53e  branchR   -> origin/branchR 
   e58e529..64ac92f  develop            -> origin/develop
Already up-to-date.
```

`> git fetch`=> nothing displayed
`> git add .` => nothing displayed
`> git commit -m "commit comment"`

```
[validation 88341a6] commit comment
X files changed, Y insertions(+), Z deletions(-)
create mode 100644 path/to/filemodified
```

This commit contains the edits I made on develop branch. Why ?

We noticed the mistake late, and a lot of work has been done since the guilty commit, rollback is not an option (I don't even know if that's possible). I just need to understand why.

Comment: If your validation branch upstream branch is origin/develop then git pull will merge origin/develop into validation.  Run git branch -vv to determine what the upstream branch is.

Comment: A [Git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) could be responsible. Is there anything in `.git/hooks/` other than the sample hooks?

Comment: `git branch -vv` : everything is as expeceted, validation on origin/validation, and same for develop. `Hooks` : only .sample files here :/

Answer (score 0):

`git push` never merges anything.

`git pull`, on the other hand, literally means: run `git fetch`, then run `git merge`.  The latter *does* merge, sometimes.  The output you show, however, suggests that there was nothing to merge.

I think what happened is much simpler: that you committed (and worked on) the wrong branch here.  If so, there may be an easy fix: check out the correct branch, use `git cherry-pick` to copy the wrong commit to the right branch, and `git branch -f validation origin/validation` to re-adjust your old `validation` branch to match your `origin/validation` (assuming you have not pushed `validation` to `origin` yet).

(Copying a commit with `git cherry-pick` means: *Turn the given commit into a change-set by comparing the specified commit's snapshot with its parent's snapshot.  Then apply this change-set to the current commit on the current branch, making a new commit from the result.*)

#### Long analysis and description

Let's take these line by line:

> ```
> > git status
> On branch validation
> ```

This means that your current branch, as of the time you ran this `git status`, is (or was) `validation`.

> ```
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/validation'.
> ```

This means that your current branch's *upstream* setting is `origin/validation`, and that both of your two names, `origin/validation` and `validation`, identify the *same commit* right now (as of the moment you ran `git status`).

> ```
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
> ```

This means that your *index* matches your current commit, and your *work-tree* (aka "working tree") matches your index.

Your index always contains a snapshot of files: this is the snapshot that will go into the new commit you make, if you make one right now.  If that snapshot matches the snapshot saved under the *current* commit, Git will say that there's nothing to commit, and sometimes claim that this means it's "empty", but the index is actually full of files at all times.  Typiically, when you `git checkout otherbranch`, Git *replaces* the index contents, changing it from "everything in the current commit of the current branch" with "everything in the tip commit of `otherbranch`".  It also replaces the work-tree contents in the same way—and then changes you over to `otherbranch`, so that the tip commit of `otherbranch` *is* the current commit, after the checkout succeeds.  This means that the index continues to match the current commit.

> At this point I code my fix.

But do you `git add` and `git commit` the result?  If so, `git add` copies the updated files from the work-tree into the index, and `git commit` makes a new commit from the index (all the un-updated files that were already in it, plus the newly-updated files from `git add`).  The new commit now matches the index, and we're back in that "everyone is happy" mode where the current commit and the index and the work-tree all match.

Note that the current branch is named `validation`, so if you *do* `git commit`, this changes the commit to which the name `validation` points, so that it points to the new commit just made.

If you did not add and commit anything, the changed files are now in the work-tree, but nowhere else.  This is a less-happy mode, because your changed files are not yet saved permanently somewhere.  Commits are (mostly) permanent, and (entirely) read-only, so once committed, those updated files are snapshotted, and thus saved forever—or at least, until you and everyone else stop using the commit, if that ever happens.

I think this is the case, that you did not run `git add` and `git commit` yet.

> Then I pull coworkers work to check for conflicts.
>
> ```
> git pull
> ```

This `git pull` ran `fetch`, which printed:

> ```
> remote: Counting objects: 81, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
> remote: Total 81 (delta 59), reused 38 (delta 22)
> Unpacking objects: 100% (81/81), done.
> From http://url-repository/project
>    659ae17..d32944f  branchC   -> origin/branchC
>    dcabc87..9d7c53e  branchR   -> origin/branchR
>    e58e529..64ac92f  develop   -> origin/develop
> ```

The lines starting with `remote:` are just information that your Git relays from the other Git, the one at `origin`, which is just commenting on how it's gathering objects to send to your Git, after shrinking them as much as possible to go over slow networks.  The `Unpacking objects` line is your Git commenting on the work it did to split them apart again.  The last four lines are your Git telling you how it's *recorded* the new information it got from the other Git:

- Their `branchC` used to point to commit `659ae17`, the last time your Git checked with their Git, but now points to commit `d32944f`.  Your Git is saving that under your name `origin/branchC`.
- Their `branchR` used to point to `dcabc87` but is now `9d7c53e`, and your Git is saving that under your name `origin/branchR`.
- Their `develop` was `e58e529` and is now `64ac92f`, and your Git is saving that under your `origin/develop`.

Then, this `git pull` ran `git merge`, which printed:

> ```
> Already up-to-date.
> ```

Since you're on your `validation` branch, and `git fetch` did not update your `origin/validation` memory of their `validation` branch, your `git merge` made no changes to anything and no new commits of any kind.  You are still on your `validation` branch, with whatever files in your work-tree, and whatever you had in your index still in your index.

> `> git fetch` => nothing displayed

That's not surprising, since `git pull` just ran `git fetch`.  Your second `git fetch` called up the other Git at `origin` again, but nothing changed *there* since the earlier calling-up, so there were no objects to package up and ship over, and no name-to-commit-hash values changed on their end to cause your Git to update your remote-tracking `origin/*` names.

Note that you are still on your `validation` branch.

> `> git add .` => nothing displayed

The `git add` command is normally silent, so this would be normal whether or not Git is copying files from your work-tree into your index.  When it's done, though, your index contents now match your work-tree contents (except for files in the work-tree that (1) were not already in the index and (2) are listed in a `.gitignore` file or other similar exclusion file).  In other words, your index is now all set for making a new commit.

> ```
> > git commit -m "commit comment"
> [validation 88341a6] commit comment
> X files changed, Y insertions(+), Z deletions(-)
> create mode 100644 path/to/filemodified
> ```

And, if I was right that you had not `git add`-ed and `git commit`-ed anything yet, you now made that commit on your own `validation` branch.  You *thought* you were on your `develop` branch, but you obviously weren't: `git status` said so earlier, and `git commit` said so just now.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information. Even if that doesn't solve my problem, some parts are new to me and welcome. Note that my git command list is exactly what I did, nothing removed so yeah, I didn't `git add`'ed and commited like you guessed. The problem is not I thought I was on develop like you said in the last part, it's that I got some develop commits into my validation branch.  
I'll go check for hooks or something, because currently it seems my commands are not the culprit.